# Returning Array or Boolean?

Tags: python, arrays, recursion, sum

Given an array of integers, find any one combination of four elements in the array whose sum is equal to a given value X. I need to return an array of all the subarray verifying the condition
I wanted to solve this problem in a recursive way , I can return whether the final condition is True or False but not returning the array of lenght 4 and the sum = X)

```py
def function(array, target):
    if len(array) == 4:
        if sum(array) == target:
            return True
        else:
            return False
    return function(array[1:], target) or function(array[:-1], target)
```

It is returning False for the array :`[7, 4, 6, -1, 1, 2]`
Instead of True

Comment: Recursion probably isn't a good fit for this problem, especially in Python.

Comment: @AMC okay I give up so :(

Answer (score 1):

Recursion is not a good way to proceed here, since you don't want to apply the same function on "reduced" arrays. You want to test all combinations, so I strongly recommand to use `itertools`.

`itertools.combinations(my_array, my_length)` makes all possible combinations `my_array`'s elements with length `my_length`, without repetition (which means order does not matter, you won't have both [a,b] and [b,a])

```
from itertools import combinations
L = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1]
target = 10

for i in combinations(L, 4):
    if sum(i) == target:
        print(i)
```

Output :

```
(1, 2, 3, 4)
(1, 3, 5, 1)
(2, 3, 4, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure wether I understand your question correctly - what I understand is that you would like to return the array and the target value in case the length of the array is indeed 4 and the target value is indeed reached. For this problem, I suppose following addition to your code:

```
def function(array, target):
if len(array) == 4:
    if sum(array) == target:
        return True
    else:
        return False

# Now this part returns array and target in case your provided conditions hold
if function(array, target) == True:
    print(array, target)
```

Did I understand your question correctly?

Comment: I would like to return the subarray instead of True / [ ] instead of False but in recursive way